# PyQt: How can I get a large list of filenames from the user?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qfiledialog

The FileDialog in pyqt is an excellent way to get one path for a file from the user, but is there a good way to get a large number of file selections from the user?

Comment: Depending on the OS, the file dialog should allow for multiple selections with the standard `Shift+Click` and `Ctrl+Click`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileNames) to allow the user to select multiple files:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Select Files', self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)

    def handleButton(self):
        title = self.button.text()
        for path in QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, title):
            print path

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to let the user use drag & drop to add files directly from their favorite file browser. As I did this in wxpython without any trouble and user-feedbacks are pretty good :)